# ASP.NET MVC Angular 2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, highcharts, angular

I am seeing some really odd behavior with typescript imports in ASP.Net MVC using Angular 2. The following code errors at run time reporting it can't find the ng2-highcharts package, from the root - not node_modules.

All other imports work - are recognized relative from node_modules.

Code:

```
import {Component, View, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Ng2Highcharts} from "ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts";
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
import EndPointService  from '../services/EndPointService';

//import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
    selector: 'index',
    providers: [EndPointService],
    templateUrl: '/Admin.Portal/App/views/view-admin-users.html',
    directives: [Ng2Highcharts]
})
export class IndexComponent ...
```

Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/Admin.Portal/ng2-highcharts/ng2-highcharts.js(…)

run @   angular2-polyfills.js:138

tsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

.csproj Typescript settings

```
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
```

I've tried importing the relative path, but then tsc fails. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `<base href="/">` that in your `<head>` element or equivalent provider in `bootstrap()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I do have that in my head yes. I don't understand why only the HighChart import isn't giving me a relative path from node_modules.

Comment: You have a problem in your config, you should add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a map entry for this into your SystemJS configuration. Something like this:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'ng2-highcharts': 'node_modules/ng2-highcharts',
    },
    packages: {
      (...)
    }
  });
  (...)
</script>
```